# Atom Override keybinding for PlatformIO

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, atom-editor

I'm using the [PlatformIO package](https://docs.platformio.org/en/latest/ide/atom.html), and I want to override the shortcut that allows me to focus in and out of the embedded terminal. The default shortcut is <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd>. I want to change it to <kbd>esc</kbd>.

I tried this in my keymap.cson:

```
'atom-text-editor':
  'esc': 'Platformio Ide Terminal: Focus'
```

I also tried with "escape" instead of "esc", but neither was able to override the default shortcut.

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Please accept the answer if it helped you solve your problem. To do so, click on the checkmark on the left side of the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The correct key for <kbd>Esc</kbd> is `esc`, but more importantly, you need to use the [correct command](https://github.com/platformio/platformio-atom-ide-terminal/blob/cb12f3127edb8364add8e53fe041aac5d28670fa/keymaps/platformio-ide-terminal.cson#L6) to focus. The following works, given that the terminal is visible.

```
'atom-text-editor':
  'escape': 'platformio-ide-terminal:focus'
```

To toggle *and* focus the terminal in one keystroke, you need to use ["composed" commands](https://flight-manual.atom.io/behind-atom/sections/keymaps-in-depth/#composed-commands). In that case, you can put something like the following into your `init.coffee`:

```
atom.commands.add "atom-workspace", "my-custom-toggle": ->
    activeEditor = atom.views.getView atom.workspace.getActiveTextEditor()

    pioTerminal = document.querySelector(".platformio-ide-terminal.terminal-view")
    parentNode = pioTerminal.parentNode if pioTerminal

    if !parentNode or parentNode.style.display is "none"
      atom.commands.dispatch(activeEditor, "platformio-ide-terminal:toggle")

    atom.commands.dispatch(activeEditor, "platformio-ide-terminal:focus")
```

And then you use that command in your `keymap.cson`:

```
'atom-text-editor':
  'escape': 'my-custom-toggle'
```